# Getting lists of indices from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get a list of indices out of a pandas dataframe.

First do an import.

```
import pandas as pd
```

Construct a pandas dataframe.

```
# Create dataframe
data = {'name': ['Jason', 'Jason', 'Tina', 'Tina', 'Tina', 'Jason', 'Tina'],
        'reports': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 5, 10],
        'coverage': [True, False, False, False, True, True, False]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  coverage   name  reports
0     True  Jason        4
1    False  Jason       24
2    False   Tina       31
3    False   Tina        2
4     True   Tina        3
5     True  Jason        5
6    False   Tina       10
```

I would like to have the indices on the left of the dataframe when the coverage is set to True, but I would like to have this for every name separately. Preferably do this without an explicit for-loop.

Desired output is something like this.

```
list_Jason = [0, 5]
list_Tina = [4]
```

Attempted solution: I thought I should use 'groupby' and then access the coverage column. From there I don't know how to proceed. All help is appreciated.

```
df.groupby('name')['coverage']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get the index out for each group.

this is stored in the 'groups' attribute of a groupbydataframe.

```
#filter for coverage==True
#group by 'name'
#access the 'groups' attribute
by_person = df[df.coverage].groupby('name').groups
```

will return:

```
{'Jason': Int64Index([0, 5], dtype='int64'),
 'Tina': Int64Index([4], dtype='int64')}
```

From which you can access the individuals as you would a regular dictionary:

```
by_person['Jason']
```

returns:

```
Int64Index([0, 5], dtype='int64')
```

Which you can treat like a regular list.

Comment: Leveraging exactly what groupby does is a good idea. Personally, I'd put it through a compression in order to put a tolist on each index object

Comment: Yup, once you have the groupby, there's probably 100's of equivalent ways to do it:

`df[df.coverage].groupby('name').apply(lambda x: x.index.tolist())`

`df[df.coverage].groupby('name').apply(lambda x: x.index.values)`

`{i:list(j) for i,j in df[df.coverage].groupby('name').groups.items()}`

Personal preference at that point

Answer (score 1):

This is doable, using `boolean indexing` first followed by the groupby:

```
In [942]: df[df.coverage].groupby('name').agg({'reports' : lambda x: list(x.index)})
Out[942]: 
      reports
name         
Jason  [0, 5]
Tina      [4]
```

You may use `dfGroupBy.agg` to get your output as a column of lists.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
  grouped=df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: x.index[x.coverage].values)
```

output:

```
name
Jason    [0, 5]
Tina        [4]
```