# Get lists out of a pandas dataframe based on row values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get lists of values out of a pandas dataframe.

First do an import.

```
import pandas as pd
```

Construct a pandas dataframe.

```
# Create dataframe
data = {'name': ['Jason', 'Jason', 'Tina', 'Tina', 'Tina', 'Jason', 'Tina'],
        'reports': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 5, 10],
        'coverage': [True, False, False, False, True, True, False]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  coverage   name  reports
0     True  Jason        4
1    False  Jason       24
2    False   Tina       31
3    False   Tina        2
4     True   Tina        3
5     True  Jason        5
6    False   Tina       10
```

I would like to have the report value when the coverage is set to True, but I would like to have this for every name separately. Preferably do this without an explicit for-loop.

Desired output is something like this.

```
list_Jason = [4, 5]
list_Tina = [3]
```

Attempted solution:

```
output3 = df[df.coverage].groupby('name').groups
```

This gives you the indices when the coverage is True for every name separately, but instead I want to have the report value.

Comment: You could have easily asked this in a comment in your initial question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799281/getting-lists-of-indices-from-pandas-dataframe/45799357

Comment: Not sure if that was against the rules of this forum. Should I delete the question?

Comment: my point is just that this is pretty much a carbon copy of the original question, with very slight tweaks. In future, you could add it as an edit to the original question. The answer here is fine though, feel free to just accept that answer; everyone loves that karma :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby` on `name` and `apply` `list` on `reports`

```
In [958]: df[df.coverage].groupby('name').reports.apply(list)
Out[958]:
name
Jason    [4, 5]
Tina        [3]
Name: reports, dtype: object
```

**Or**, store them as `dicts`

```
In [959]: df[df.coverage].groupby('name').reports.apply(list).to_dict()
Out[959]: {'Jason': [4, 5], 'Tina': [3]}
```

Comment: Can you also directly only keep the last of the elements? So that the output is 'Jason': 5 and 'Tina': 3